# How to print a list as a set, but without removing duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list such as:

```
myList = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

I would like to print this as set listing notation:

```
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2}
```

However, when I try to print this as a set, the duplicates are removed:

```
>>> set(mylist)
{0, 1, 2}
```

I do not want the duplicates to be removed. How can I print with set syntax, but without removing any duplicates?

Comment: Sets are by definition `unordered collections of unique elements`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @kuro You're quite right. I've actually just realised my mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like simple string manipulation would work:

```
list_str = str(mylist).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}')
```

Or, perhaps even better, we can just slice off the first and last characters of the list formatted string and replace them with the new braces that you want:

```
list_str = '{%s}' % (str(mylist)[1:-1])
```

This is better for the obvious reason that it doesn't have a chance to mess with the contents of the list (imagine using the previous code if your list contained strings that may or may not have `'['` characters embedded in them).

If that still doesn't sit well with you, you can format the whole string yourself in a number of ways (usually involving getting a string representation of each item and joining them with a comma and space).

```
list_str = '{%s}' % (', '.join(repr(item) for item in mylist))
list_str = '{%s}' % (', '.join(map(repr, mylist)))
```

Comment: If only `print` had a `begin=`... `print(*mylist, sep=', ', end='}')`

Comment: @JonClements -- Yeah, but you can fake it if you don't mind using _2_ print calls:  `print('{', end=''); print(*mylist, sep=', ', end='}\n')`